# Stack unwinding with no frame pointer on x86

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

Is it possible to get gdb to successfully unwind stacks of code compiled with gcc using `-fomit-frame-pointer` on x86 (similar to AMD64)?  If so, what is required to get this working?

Just to be clear: I can recompile, so compiler options are OK but I can't disable omitting the frame pointer.

Comment: Why can't you remove `-fomit-frame-pointer` from your compiler option? You want apparently to ask the compiler to remove the frame pointer and to not remove it: a contradiction from your part! What happens with your code if compiled without `-fomit-frame-pointer` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch A decision was made to compile without a frame pointer on x86.  While I could personally compile a local instance with frame pointers, that doesn't help when trying to debug test failures that use the centrally built binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler option I was looking for was `-fasynchronous-unwind-tables`

Comment: It's okay to accept your own answer.  I think you should in this case.

Comment: Done, thanks.  Was mostly waiting for the blackout period to expire